# Regular expression for splitting complex string

Tags: regex

I have a string like

```
if((param5 > param6) || ((param7 < param8) && (param9 < param10)))
```

Using regex I need to split this into:

```
(param5 > param6) || ((param7 < param8) && (param9 < param10))
```

then

```
(param7 < param8) && (param9 < param10)
```

Comment: There is more than splitting involved here. Also, this is not enough information. How variable are those strings, what are the exact rules for breaking up this string? To me, this looks more like a job for a parser, not a regex.

Comment: I agree with Tim here. Regex ins't particularly "good" at counting parenthesis to determine which closing parenthesis belongs to a particular opening parenthesis. There _are_ regex flovors that are capable of recusive matching, but what will you do then? You'd have a bunch of matches which you'd then need to evaluate: mind as well use a parser that is able to parse the input _and_ evaluate it in one go.